# How to define if object is equal to null in magnolia freemarker(.ftl)

Tags: nodes, freemarker, jcr, magnolia

I am currently working on piece of component, I need an if else statement to be done to filter out wether a page object is null or not, here is my attempts:

```
[#assign page = cmsfn.page(component)]
[#if page IS NULL ] // not working...
   [@cms.component content=cmsfn.asContentMap(component) editable=false/]
[/#if]
```

and this one

```
[#assign page = cmsfn.page(component)]
[#if !page?has_content ] // not working...
   [@cms.component content=cmsfn.asContentMap(component) editable=false/]
[/#if]
```

What I am trying to do here is,  if the page object is null , then do the component rending, these page object are jrc children nodes, when rendering component this type of node mess up thing template, so I need to filter out and make sure the page is null, then render.

Any suggestions? please provide me a code example.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template language of FreeMarker (2.x) has this... quirk, that it doesn't have a `null` value. Thus, you can't store `null` in a variable. When you have `foo.bar` where `bar` corresponds to Java `getBar()` which return `null`, then as far as the template language is concerned, `foo` simply doesn't contain `bar`. And, referring to something that doesn't exist is illegal, unless, you apply a `null`/missing handler operator *directly* on the referring expression (like `foo.bar!'myDefault'` or `foo.bar??`).

So the simplest approach is to avoid the assignment like `[#if cmsfn.page(component)??]...[/#if]`. But sometimes that's not acceptable as then you have to get the `page` for a second time further down. Then you can use some default that you can differentiate from the non-default. Assuming that for a `page` object `?has_content` gives `true` (and unless you are using some strange `ObjectWrapper` it does), a default value like `{}` (empty hash) suffices. The `exp!` operator can be used as a shorthand, as it also gives a default value for which `?has_content` is false:

```
[#assign page = cmsfn.page(component)!]
[#if page?has_content]
   [@cms.component content=cmsfn.asContentMap(component) editable=false/]
   ... Do something with `page`, otherwise we need not use #assign.
[#else]
   ... Don't do anything with `page`, it's that strange default object.
[/#if]
```